# Type ‘serial::serial’ names the constructor, not the type in C/C++

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, syntax-error

Using Eclipse on Ubuntu Im attempting to define the function:

```
serial::serial new_serial(){
    serial handle = new serial;
    handle.setName("ttyUSB0");

    return handle;
}
```

Is tripping up the compiler and causing it to show an error.

```
Type ‘serial::serial’ names the constructor, not the type
```

How can this be fixed? Whats causing it to error out?

Comment: Is `serial` a class? Are you trying to define a static method of `serial` which constructs an instance on the heap?

Comment: What I was trying to do is pass back a serial object from the function, similar to the way a constructor does.

Answer (score 3):

Just what the message says:  you have a class called `serial`, and it contains a constructor function that's also named `serial`, so `serial::serial` means the `serial` function within the `serial` class.  You can't use that as a function's return type, because the return type has to be a *type*, such as a class.

You probably want your function's return type to be either `serial` (returning an instance of the class by value) or something pointer-like, e.g. `serial*`, or (preferably) `std::unique_ptr<serial>`.  But it's unclear whether you want to return an object or a pointer, because the line

```
serial handle = new serial;
```

is also erroneous.  The `new` returns a pointer, and you can't assign a pointer to a variable that's meant to hold an object.  (You may be thinking of Java or C#, where most variables are references.  C++ is different.)

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a class `serial` in a namespace `serial` by any chance?

If so, you are asking for trouble. The name lookup rules generally trips on this, since ADL has possibly enabled the namespace for name lookup. In that case `serial::serial` could mean the class `serial` in the namespace `serial`. Or, it could be class `serial`'s constructor.

A typical solution is to name namespaces in plural: `serials::serial`.

On the other hand you use `serial` unqualified inside the factory function, so quite possibly Wyzard has nailed your problem...

Comment: What I'm trying to do is use a factory method or function and return serial object configured with hard coded defaults as a result.

Comment: @BobR: Since you tagged this with C++11, I assume you can use C++11 features. In that case you probably want to look at Sutter's latest factory function [GotW 90](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/30/gotw-90-solution-factories/).